# Format Exception On Date time c#

Tags: c#

hello i have this format exception on datetime, how can solve this error, i have read data from database of access and now i have upload this data on sql server database

[image: EXCEPTION IMAGE]

```
string dbserver2 = textBox4.Text;
            string dbname2 = textBox1.Text;
            string dbusername2 = textBox2.Text;
            string dbpassword2 = textBox3.Text;


            SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + dbserver2 + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbname2 + ";User ID=" + dbusername2 + ";Password=" + dbpassword2 + "");

            conn2.Open();

            string queryset2 = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Articolo ON ";

            string query2 = "INSERT INTO Articolo (CodMarca,CodArt,Fornitore,Descrizione,UM,Prezzo,PrezzoListino,DataAggiornamento) VALUES(@CodMarca,@CodArt,@Fornitore,@Descrizione,@UM,@Prezzo,@PrezzoListino,@DataAggiornamento)";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query2, conn2);

            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodMarca", CodMarca);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodArt", CodArt);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fornitore", Fornitore);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descrizione", Descrizione);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UM", UM);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prezzo", System.Convert.ToDecimal(PrezzoNetto));
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrezzoListino", System.Convert.ToDecimal(PrezzoCasa));

            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DataAggiornamento);

            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataAggiornamento", dt);

            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn2.Close();
```

Comment: What is the value of `PrezzoCasa`?

Comment: prezzo casa is string conver to decimal into database is type money

Comment: So, what is its value? That is what Soner asked you.

Answer (score 3):

`Convert.ToDecimal` uses `Decimal.Parse` under the hood and it uses your `CurrentCulture` settings *by default*.

Probably your current culture uses [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator) rather than a `,` string, that's why your code throws `FormatException`. Even if your current culture settings use [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator) as a `,`, this would return `444` as a result.

As a solution, you can [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone) your culture and set this `NumberDecimalSeparator` property to , and use *that* cloned culture as a second parameter when you parsing it.

```
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
```

and

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrezzoListino", Convert.ToDecimal(PrezzoCasa, clone));
```

A few things more;

- Don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.